# Statistical analysis of the results calculated from a stochastic global optimization

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, optimization

I recently use the *Basinhopping* algorithm [1], a Monte Carlo Markov Chain variant, to find the global minimum of numerical functions (which are not necessarily smooth).  Though the global optimization algorithm usually outputs a reasonably small global minimum, I have no idea how to get a statistical meaning, *e.g.*, the confidence interval,  about the calculated global minimum.

**Question**: In a typical stochastic global optimization, how do people perform the uncertainty test on their prediction?  In my concrete case, the numerical function $f$ is guaranteed to be non-negative, and thus the global minimum $f^*$, if found, necessarily satisfies

$$f^*\geq 0.$$

From time to time, however, the true global minimum, denoted by $$f^*_{true},$$ differs from the one produced by the algorithm. Then my question can be more precisely stated as: Is there a way to estimate $$\text{Probability} ( f^*_{true} = 0~|~ f^* =0)? $$

> [1] Wales, David J., and Jonathan PK Doye. "Global optimization by
>   basin-hopping and the lowest energy structures of Lennard-Jones
>   clusters containing up to 110 atoms." The Journal of Physical
>   Chemistry A 101, no. 28 (1997): 5111-5116.

Comment: Are you only interested in the uncertainty in the globally optimal objective value, and not the uncertainty as to the one or more argmin values which achieve it?  Those are different "beasts".  In any event, good luck - you'll need it.

Comment: Thanks for raising this point. My problem setting is more directly related to   the globally optimal objective value;  I agree with you on the importance of the argmin.